# Deleting groups of countries from dataframe indexes

Tags: python

I have a dataframe, where I have set indexes as countries. However there are also groups of countries such as Sub-Saharan Africa (IDA & IBRD countries) or Middle East & North Africa (IDA & IBRD countries). I want to delete them. I want just countries to stay.

Example imput dataframe where indexes are:

```
Antigua and Barbuda
Angola
Arab World
```

Wanted output dataframe:

```
Antigua and Barbuda
Angola
```

My idea was using pycountry, however it does nothing.

```
countr=list(pycountry.countries)
for idx in df.index:
    if idx in countr :
            continue
    else:
        df.drop(index=idx)
```

Comment: `pycountry.countries` is not just a list of names but a list of objects, I presume you just want to compare on `country.name`, e.g. `countr = set(country.name for country in pycountry.countries)`. There are better way using boolean indexing, e.g. `df = df[df.index.isin(countr)]`

Comment: Is that how `pycountry.countries` work? It returns a country object, not the name to be compared with the value in the index, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your list of country names:

```
countries_list = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    countries_list.append(country.name)
```

Checking output:

```
>>> print(countries_list[0:5])
['Aruba', 'Afghanistan', 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Åland Islands']
```

You can do this if you want to get a dataframe of countries that are in your countries list:

```
import pycountry
import pandas as pd


country = {'Country Name': ['Antigua and Barbuda','USSR', 'United States', 'Germany','The Moon']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=country)

countries_list = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    countries_list.append(country.name)

new_df = []

for i in df['Country Name']:
    if i in countries_list:
        new_df.append(i)
```

Checking output:

```
>>> print(new_df)
['Antigua and Barbuda', 'United States', 'Germany']
```

Otherwise, for your specific code, try this:

Assuming you have your data in a dataframe 'df':

```
import pandas as pd
import pycountry

countries_list = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    countries_list.append(country.name)

for idx in df.index:
    if idx in countries_list:
            continue
    else:
        df.drop(index=idx)
```

Let me know if this works for you.